# Union of extended types get parsed as base type

Tags: javascript, zod

I want to parse an array of different schemas that depend on a base type :

```js
// Simple example
const typeA = z.object({ prop: z.string() });

const typeB = typeA.extend({
  extraProp: z.boolean(),
});
```

I tried with the following schema :

```js
const schema = z.array(z.union([typeA, typeB]));
```

The thing is when I parse the data, the `typeB` items get parsed as `type A`, so the `extraProp` is removed from the output

```js
const data = schema.parse([{ prop: 'foo', extraProp: true }]);
// => [{"prop":"foo"}]
```

When I put `typeB` as the first item of the union, it seems to output the right type, but when wrong data is sent, it is parsed to `typeA`, :

```js
const schema = z.array(z.union([typeB, typeA]));

const data = schema.parse([{ prop: 'foo', extraProp: true }]);
// => [{"prop":"foo","extraProp":true}]

...

const data = schema.parse([{ prop: 'foo', extraProp: 4 }]);
// => [{"prop":"foo"}] - should fail here
```

Is my schema wrong here or is it something that zod is not capable of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From zod's [Unions](https://zod.dev/?id=unions) section (emphasis added):

> Zod will test the input against each of the "options" in order and return **the first value** that validates successfully.

Nothing more and nothing less: in `z.union([typeA, typeB])` it tries
`typeA` and if it validates, returns the parsed data, if not, it would
try `typeB`, and so on.

One tends to think that it computes some form of a united object schema,
but it doesn't. Which explains why the last example validates: `typeB` fails,
then it just parses `typeA`, like there's no `typeB`.

And one is right to expect that - it doesn't validate, for instance, in
TypeScript:

```typescript
type A = {prop: string};
type B = A & {extraProp: boolean};
type Sch = B | A;

const o: Sch = { prop: 'foo', extraProp: 2 }; 
// error TS2322: type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

The construct that would emulate the expected behavior in both case is
[`.merge`](https://zod.dev/?id=merge):

```js
const typeA = z.object({ prop: z.string() });
const typeB = typeA.extend({
   extraProp: z.boolean(),
});

const schema = z.array(typeB.merge(typeA));
const data = schema.parse([{ prop: 'foo', extraProp: 2 }]);
//{prop: 'foo', extraProp: true}
```

```js
// ......
const schemaBA = z.array(typeB.merge(typeA));
schemaBA.parse([{ prop: 'foo', extraProp: 2 }]);

//Uncaught ZodError: [{
//  //......
//  "message": "Expected boolean, received number"
// }]
```